# GPU not captured by TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I installed `tensorflow` using `pip install tensorflow` within Anaconda virtual environment on Windows.

I tried to test whether GPU is enabled, and type

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

and got

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

My system does have CUDA and CUDNN enabled, as I do not have a problem installing PyTorch GPU version. How do I enable GPU for TensorFlow?

Comment: When you import tensorflow, some logs are printed to the terminal, they contain all the information you need on why the GPU is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, uninstall tensorflow using,

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Install `tensorflow-gpu` version,

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
```

If using pip did't work you can try with `conda install command.`

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

This will automatically install `CUDA & cuDNN.`
Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I remove the existing virtual environment, and re-install in the newly created virtual environment, but it still fails

Comment: Check with 'nvidia-smi' in termila. If the gpu driver is properly installed.

Comment: @ashraful16, it turns out that this conda install approach finally solves the problem. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cpu version tensorflow using `pip uninstall tensorflow` and install the gpu version of the tensorflow, `pip install tensorflow-gpu`.

You can check this tutorial [link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows-cuda-cudnn/) as well.

It can be summarized by the following steps:

1. Uninstall your old tensorflow
2. Install tensorflow-gpu pip install tensorflow-gpu
3. Install Nvidia Graphics Card & Drivers (you probably already have)
4. Download & Install CUDA
5. Download & Install cuDNN
6. Verify with your program.

Comment: @Sauray, I followed this but did not get the issue fixed. My guess might be the cudnn and cuda version may not match the Tensorflow version. It turns out that the conda install option works as suggested in the above. Thank you very much for your answer as well.

Comment: Sure, happy that your query got fixed. Cheers :)