# tensorflow 2.4.1 doesnt detect gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm kind of new to machine/deep learning. I installed TensorFlow versions 2.4.1, I have CUDA version 11.2 but and cudNN when I want to get a list of available GPUs it returns nothing.(my GPU is 1050 ti 4GB)

I tried to install tensorflow-gpu but nothing changed.

what should I do?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65972286/13621630)

Comment: @Anthraxff, Is your issue resolved now? Else, you can try to downgrade your `CUDA` version from `11.2` to `11.0`, since `Tensorflow 2.4` is compatible with `CUDA 11.0` and `CuDNN 8.0`. For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). Thanks!